# pandas Calculate time difference in same column?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to figure out the time elapsed in a dataset, based off the id (`name`) and login time(`login_time`) for each individual. I want to see the time elapsed between the first `login_time` and the final `login_time` for each individual listed in this df:

example of the data:

```
name   login_time
alex   2020-12-18T10:50:35
alex   2020-12-19T11:50:11
sue    2020-10-15T10:00:35
sue    2020-10-16T09:50:22
```

Unfortunately, the actual dataset has over 800,000 rows. If it just the sample data I would just do this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('filepathto.csv')

df.apply(lambda x: x[x['name'] == 'alex'].login_time.max()
) - df.apply(lambda x: x[x['name'] == 'alex'].login_time.min()) #repeat for sue
```

My question is, how can I scale this or is there a better method to be able to get the results I'm looking for (elapsed time from first time recorded to last time recorded)?

edit: DF has 27 columns, not just 2. The two listed are just what I'm interested in for this process.

Comment: `df.groupby("name").diff()`?

Comment: probably safer to do groupby on the name, get the ```first``` and ```last``` and do the difference. that should cover for groups that have a count greater than 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the index of `df` is the `name` column. I would use the following method:

```
df.groupby('name').max() - df.groupby('name').min()
```

Because there are only 2 columns in `df`, the [group value](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min) of  `df.groupby('name')` would be the values in the `login_time` column.

`login_time` is the only column other than`name`.

If you have more than 2 columns in `df`, use the following code to specify `login_time` column:

```
df.groupby('name')['login_time'].max() - df.groupby('name')['login_time'].min()
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? How does it work vis-a-vis knowing to look in the `login_time` column?

Comment: also, the dataframe has more than 2 columns (27) so I don't know if this would apply. Probably should have included that in the OP.

Comment: Hi, @noscodemos. I've added the code for the `df` that has more than 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df['login_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['login_time'])

df1 = df.groupby('name')['login_time'].agg(['min','max'])
print (df1)
                     min                 max
name                                        
alex 2020-12-18 10:50:35 2020-12-19 11:50:11
sue  2020-10-15 10:00:35 2020-10-16 09:50:22

df2 = df1['max'].sub(df1['min']).reset_index(name='diff')
print (df2)
   name            diff
0  alex 1 days 00:59:36
1   sue 0 days 23:49:47
```

Or if performance is not important:

```
df2 = (df.groupby('name')['login_time']
         .agg(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
         .reset_index(name='diff'))
```